# Securing each microservices

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I have two microservices, that should communicate with each other.
My example: Microservice A make a request to Microservice B. Users should not have access, only other microservices. I thought, that solution might be “Http Basic Authentication”, so microservice A should also send username and password to microservice B. That’s fine, but how microservice A should find out that username and password? I am using Eureka as a Discovery Service, but I haven't found anything, that can help my in this case. I only found eureka.client.proxy-user-name and eureka.client.proxy-password, but it didn’t worked for me.

Comment: Where are you deploying your microservices? Are you using Kubernetes/Openshift?

Comment: @nitgeek i’m new to cloud development, so currently i’m not deploying it.

Comment: If you are going to deploy to Kubernetes the secrets are used to store credentials. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/

Comment: You'll use Gateway service which will have authentication instead of all the microservices. So MS-A will communicate with MS-B via Gateway.

Answer (score 1):

1. Extract the Authorization header from request to Micro Service A add that header inside
   HTTP Header and make request to Micro service B. Spring Security will validate the header and allow authentication

   ```
   private WebClient client = null;

   @PostConstruct
   public void init() {
       client = WebClient.builder().baseUrl("some-url").build();
   }

   @GetMapping("/getCandidateById/{institutionId}/{id}")
   public Mono<Candidate> getCandidateById(@PathVariable String institutionId, @PathVariable String id, ServerHttpRequest request) {
           return client.get()
                   .uri("/getCandidateById/{institutionId}/{id}", institutionId, id)
                   /*main logic*/.header("Authorization", request.getHeaders().getFirst("Authorization"))
                   .retrieve()
                   .bodyToMono(Candidate.class);
   }
   ```

I am extracting header and adding it inside the request which i making by WebClient.
Similarly you can use RestTemplate also.

**Note: I have used Basic Authentication**